# Short[] to byte[] gives original data out of order

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have a `short[]` that contains the pixel data of a `tiff` image. I want to convert it to a `byte[]` with the below code. Technically, the below code does the conversion. However, when I write the resulting bytes to a raw file and compare them to the original bytes of the image (before being run through my program), some of the bytes are switched around. It almost looks like the endianness of the bytes is switched, but it's not happening on every byte block. I've tried using different conversion methods from code I've found on StackOverflow and other forums, but I'm consistently getting the same result. Is there something implicit to how Java handles bytes that is causing this problem?

Code:

```
public static byte[] convert(short[] bytesAsShort) {
    int j = 0;
    int length = bytesAsShort.length;
    byte[] byteData = new byte[length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        byteData[j++] = (byte) (bytesAsShort[i] >>> 8);
        byteData[j++] = (byte) (bytesAsShort[i] >>> 0);
    }
    return byteData;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if there's anything I can do to make my question clearer. Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
Some sample bytes as hex values (included more for a better sample size), before:

```
 FF 00 01 01 A0 00 A5 00 A0 00 A3 00 8F 00 AB 00 D4 00 08 01
```

After:

```
 FF 01 01 00 A0 00 A5 00 A0 00 A3 00 8F 00 AB 00 D4 01 08 00
```

Yeah, definitely looks like the endianness is switched. Gonna test something real quick.

**UPDATE 2:** Another function I've tried for conversion:

```
public static byte[] convert(short[] bytesAsShort) {
    int index;
    int iterations = bytesAsShort.length;

    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytesAsShort.length * 2);

    for (index = 0; index != iterations; ++index) {
        bb.putShort(bytesAsShort[index]);
    }

    return bb.array();
}
```

Comment: Sample data would help. Both input and expected output vs real output

Comment: Bytes and shorts are implicitly sign-extended to int whenever you do arithmetic with them, but it's more of an issue when you are converting the other way, for example byte to short or short to int. Your cast to a byte in the example code truncates the extended bits.

Comment: If it only affects some bytes then it probably occurs elsewhere, perhaps when you read or write the data.

Comment: @BackSlash Added some sample bytes from the two files.

Comment: @Radiodef Is there a good way in java to avoid truncating the extended bits?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck After extensive testing, I can say definitively it is definitely the array conversion that is causing the problem. I've compared raw outputs of the data at every other step of my code, and differences only arise immediately after the conversion step.

Comment: It looks as though you've read the shorts starting from the second byte. If you skip first 00 in "before"

Comment: You probably want to truncate the extended bits. Sign extension is like this: if, say, the MSB of the short is set, then fill all of the high 16 bits in the int with 1s. So a short value `0b1000_0000_0000_0000` turns in to an int value `0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1000_0000_0000_0000`. This preserves the two's complement numeric value of the short but it changes the binary value. It would be a problem if you wanted to do something with shorts as if they were unsigned values, but in the example code you've posted here it shouldn't make a difference. It could be happening somewhere else, though.

Comment: This conversion is Big Endian, is that intended? It just looks immediately suspicious to me because it's pretty rare

Comment: @harold The test image I'm working with is Big Endian, yes. I'll show you some of the other code I was using for conversion where the user can specify big or little endian. This new code also gives the same result. EDIT: Strike that. I can't find the function in my code. It is probably on one of the other branches/commits I've been developing on. But I did include a third method that I was testing.

Comment: Well, it should do a correct Big Endian short-to-byte conversion, at least I see no reason why it wouldn't. Are you sure it can't be a problem somewhere else?

Comment: @harold Well, rule of thumb says it could always be a problem elsewhere I suppose. I'm going to do some more testing and see if I can't shine some light on this issue. With any luck, my next activity on the question will be an answer.

Comment: Here's an example on Ideone showing the problem isn't in the code in the question, as well as demonstrating what would happen if there was a sign extension issue. http://ideone.com/wW0OUm (Judging by your sample data, I doubt the issue is related to sign extension, but it's something to know about, anyway. If it were related to sign extension, there would more typically be spurious high bits set to 1, as in the Ideone program.)

Comment: If you divide the data into 4 byte chunks, it looks like the 2nd and 4th bytes has switched places in each chunk.

Comment: Not that I believe this to be the source of your problem, but the entire loop in your second approach can be replaced with `bb.asShortBuffer().put(bytesAsShort);`.

Answer (score 0):

The following unit test demonstrates that the conversion function listed in the question correctly converts the sample data also from the question.

Therefore the problem that you are experiencing is elsewhere, and is not currently listed in the question.  The problem is either in the loading of the data, or the writing of it (perhaps both).   I recommend that you write a unit test that knows the starting data, and asserts the output data as it appears on disk.  This will help you to track down where the problem lies.  If it does not, then please post that complete unit test and we will help you further.

```
// unmodified convert method
public static byte[] convert(short[] bytesAsShort) {
    int j = 0;
    int length = bytesAsShort.length;
    byte[] byteData = new byte[length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        byteData[j++] = (byte) (bytesAsShort[i] >>> 8);
        byteData[j++] = (byte) bytesAsShort[i];
    }
    return byteData;
}


@Test
public void testConversion() {
    short[] orig= new short[] {(short) 0xFF00, (short) 0x0101, (short) 0xA000, (short) 0xA500,
        (short) 0xA000, (short) 0xA300, (short) 0x8F00, (short) 0xAB00, (short) 0xD400, (short) 0x0801};

    // same bytes as orig, but broken up into 8 bits rather than 16
    byte[] expected= new byte[] {(byte) 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, (byte)0xA0, 0x00, (byte)0xA5,
        0x00, (byte)0xA0, 0x00, (byte)0xA3,
        0x00, (byte)0x8F, 0x00, (byte)0xAB, 0x00, (byte)0xD4, 0x00, 0x08, 0x01};

    byte[] result = convert( orig );

    assertBytesEqual( expected, result );
}

private void assertBytesEqual( byte[] expected, byte[] actual ) {
    assertEquals( expected.length, actual.length );

    for ( int i=0; i<expected.length; i++ ) {
        assertEquals( i+": "+expected[i] + " != " + actual[i], expected[i], actual[i] );
    }
}
```